# Can I quote an article which license is CC-BY-ND

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, derivative-work

I have a question about direct quotations (i.e. "copy-and-paste" portions of a work - with ellipses "[...]" if necessary -) and paraphrasing the content of a text article which license is CC-BY-ND. As far as I can understand, I cannot produce something which qualifies as a "Derivative Work" from the original article (it's a text article, published on a website), but does that mean I'm unable to:

- to share a work which quotes those articles (there is more than one, all with the same license), directly with quotation marks or by paraphrasing the content?
- to share a work which summarizes the ideas written in one or more of those articles?
- to share a work which summarizes the ideas written in one or more of those articles *and adds some personal opinions/instructions on how to follow those articles advice*?

I understand that the definition of **adapted material** of that license is:

> Adapted Material means material subject to Copyright and Similar Rights that is derived from or based upon the Licensed Material and in which the Licensed Material is translated, altered, arranged, transformed, or otherwise modified in a manner requiring permission under the Copyright and Similar Rights held by the Licensor

but how are the former points related with this definition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The licence does not allow you to do this

**However, copyright law may.**

You work is (probably) an adaptation within the terms of the licence and these are not allowed. So, put the licence aside and consider if your use is [fair use or fair dealing](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/48359/344); if it is, you are allowed to do it notwithstanding the licence.

Comment: Is this valid also for (in)direct quotations?